# Universal way to transform right recursion to left one

Tags: bison, yacc

I am recently working with Flex and Bison. I know that generally the latter one does not work well with right recursion due to stack size. On the other hand most of the grammar problems are easily solvable with right recursion. AFAIK there is universal algorithm to change left recursion to the right one. Is there any that works opposite way?

Here is simple example:

```
expression:
    number
  | expression operation number
  | expression operation openRound expression closeRound
  | openRound expression closeRound
```

You can treat number and operation as terminals, as they are irrelevant in the example.

Comment: Your example grammar is left-recursive, so I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are algorithms which can remove either left- or right-recursion from a grammar (but not both). The two algorithms are simple mirrors of each other, so you can derive the algorithm for removing right-recursion from the algorithm for removing left-recursion.

However, these algorithms do not preserve parse trees. That doesn't matter if you are merely trying to *recognize* whether a string is in the language or not, but it is not very useful when you really want to parse the string, where parse means "analyze the syntactic structure of the string". In this case, producing the incorrect parse tree is not at all helpful.

Furthermore, the algorithms do not necessarily preserve membership in the set of LR(1) languages, so it is also possible that the resulting grammar is no longer parseable (or even recognizable) using the LR(1) parsing algorithm.

<opinion>
In any case, I dispute the claim that "most... grammar problems are easily solvable with right recursion". In fact, most practical parsing problems are more easily solved with left-recursion, including the example grammar at the end of the question (which is left-recursive). Rearranging such a grammar to be right-recursive so that it can be handled by an LL parser can be quite an annoying process whose end result is less readable than the original left-recursive grammar.
</opinion>